# how can i pass value to another from the date checkin1 to another another date checkin1 after i click the button of the 1st value

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am using an example of JQuery DatePicker
But, i want the date to pass to another date with the same input of the datepicker. I am not sure how to change this.

Any help would be appereicate it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the onSelect option in your datepicker instantiation. For example:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
  onSelect: function(){
              //"this" refers to #datepicker in this context
              $('#other-datepicker').val($(this).val());
            }
});
```

The onSelect function gets called when the user picks a date for #datepicker.

EDIT for your code:

replace:

```
$( "#pickdate" ).datepicker({minDate: +0});
```

with:

```
$( "#pickdate" ).datepicker({
    minDate: +0,
    onSelect: function(){ $('#easy-form-from').val($(this).val());  }
});
```

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).onselect(function(){
    /*alert ('test');*/
    jQuery('#easy-form-from').val("#pickdate").val());
    
    
    });
                </script>

Comment: How are you declaring the field as a datepicker?

Comment: What i've posted needs be done to the jquery code you've used to turn the #pickdate field into a datepicker field. Are you using http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: Then somewhere there is a statement in your javascript that looks like: $( "#pickdate" ).datepicker();   correct?

Comment: yeah your right
$( "#pickdate" ).datepicker({minDate: +0});
$( "#pickdate1" ).datepicker ({minDate: +1});

Comment: yeah i forgot., sorry., i can only check., i cannot vote since im new here ^_^ thank you again